# Join tables on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this classic sql problem `How many copies of the book titled The Lost Tribe are owned by each library branch?`

I solved this by getting the branches that have copies but is there a way to get all the branches and this fill in the noOfCopies that contain the title and enter null if not? I've tried left, inner and right joins but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
select l.branchName,  r.noOfCopies

from (tbl_library_branch as l
join tbl_book_copies as r
on l.branchId = r.branchId)
right join  tbl_book as bk
on r.bookId = bk.bookId
where title in ('The Lost Tribe');
```

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: You might look into sql set operators like 'union'. You might also consider the 'if null' function to replace null values with zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're after something like the following. Start from the table you require all rows from and *outer join* to the result of filtering your book by title:

```
select b.branchName, coalesce(c.noOfCopies,0) noOfCopies
from tbl_library_branch b
left join (
    select bc.branchId, bc.noOfCopies
    from tbl_book b 
    join tbl_book_copies bc on bc.bookId=b.bookId
    where b.title = 'The Lost Tribe'
)c on c.branchId = b.branchId;
```

Comment: Thank you.
When you do left join and then () this returns a joined b and bc table which we call c?

Comment: Yes, the terminology for this is a *derived table* - the result of this query is considered a table in its own right for the join.